# Validation of numbers with decimal values in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox

how to restrict user to enter only numbers with 6 digits and two decimal values in textbox using javascript??

```
//Function to allow only numbers to textbox
function validate(key) {
    //getting key code of pressed key
    var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
    var phn = document.getElementById('txtPhn');
    //comparing pressed keycodes
    if ((keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (phn.value.length < 6) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
var txtBudget = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtBudget');
    txtBudget.addEventListener('input', function (prev)
     {
        return function (evt) {
            if (!/^\d{0,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value)) {
                this.value = prev;
            }
            else {
                prev = this.value;
            }
        };
    } (txtBudget.value), false);
```

Comment: Note you want to cover keycodes 96 - 105, which are the numeric keypad as well. You should also cover the backspace, tab and arrow keys too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

foo.addEventListener('input', function (prev) {
    return function (evt) {
        if (!/^\d{0,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value)) {
          this.value = prev;
        }
        else {
          prev = this.value;
        }
    };
}(foo.value), false);​
```

The code is not cross-browser compliant, but it should give you a hint of how it can be done.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v4tGc/

---

**Update**: not using the *input* event.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

foo.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
    var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
    if (!/^\d{0,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(value)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);​
```

Comment: how to call this function in onkeypress event of the textbox ??

Comment: but how you call this evt.preventDefault();

Comment: @kk1076 I don't quite get what you mean?!

Comment: its working fine with input as in demo .. but its not working in keypress ?.

Answer (score 0):

```
**When I Googling, found a code. And then i modify to what i need. And I think it will help you**.

    **HTML**

        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>JS Bin</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <input type="text" id="sal" name="sal" onkeypress="return isDecimalNumber(event,this)">
            </body>
        </html>

    **Javascript**



<script type="text/javascript">

            function isDecimalNumber(evt, c) {
                var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
                var dot1 = c.value.indexOf('.');
                var dot2 = c.value.lastIndexOf('.');

                if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                    return false;
                else if (charCode == 46 && (dot1 == dot2) && dot1 != -1 && dot2 != -1)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }

        </script>
```